# Asynchronous action method in ASP .NET MVC 5 Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm working on ASP .NET MVC 5 app and I'm thinking about asynchronous action method and where to use it.

For example in index action method, I'm using:

```
var topics = db.Topic.Where(t => t.State == MessageState.Allowed).OrderByDescending(topic => topic.DatePosted).ToList();
```

Should I use here async? Or is there some tips where to use async?

Another question: is better to use `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` ?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is an Entity Framework question, not an MVC question. It's a lot easier to find an answer if you search for the correct technology/library/framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are async overloads for EF and LINQ.

Instead of `.ToList()` you want to use `.ToListAsync()` etc.

Check [System.Data.Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx) namespace from Entity Framework package.

```
   public async Task<List<Topic>> Get() {
        return await db.Topic
                  .Where(t => t.State == MessageState.Allowed)
                  .OrderByDescending(topic => topic.DatePosted)
                  .ToListAsync();
   }
```

Make sure you understand what async/await does and implication of doing async controller methods. It is really easy to screw up here. I'd recommend to read some of this (in no particular order):

- [Async and await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
- [Async and await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx)
- [Async Worth the await](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/04/03/async-in-4-5-worth-the-await/)
- [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps: Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) (and read Part 1 and Part 3 too)
- [Asynchronous gotchas in C#](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/)
- [Potential pitfalls to avoid when passing around async lambdas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx)
- [Psychic Debugging of Async Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/28/psychic-debugging-of-async-methods.aspx)

Comment: And is better to use Async version in example above? In action method is just that call and then return View call. Thank's for answer!

Comment: @E_N_T_E_R It is better to either use async everywhere or not use it at all. Mixing async and sync can lead to issues that are really to debug.

Comment: Definitely, in fact this is the most usual scenario. The asynchronous call releases the thread while waiting for the database to respond. Otherwise you'd block a thread that could be used to service other requests. That's a *huge* win on high-traffic sites or small VMs. It's also very easy to implement